# Get attribute of clicked div with dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I need to get the 'role' attribute of a div with a dynamically generated ID in regards to the below code.

HTML:

```
<div id="renable0" role="0">
     false
</div>
<div id="renable1" role="1">
    true
</div>
<!-- THE LIST OF DIVS CONTINUES IN INCREASING INCREMENTS OF 1 -->
```

Javascript:

```
$("[id^='renable']").editInPlace({ // editInPlace is a jQuery plugin
    url: 'save.php',
    params: 'pos='+$(this).attr('role') // How can I get this role attribute for the clicked div?
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a `.each()` loop:

```
$("[id^='renable']").each(function() {
    $(this).editInPlace({
        url: 'save.php',
        params: 'pos='+$(this).attr('role')
    });
});
```

It would be nice if `editInPlace` allowed the `params` option to be a function, like some other jQuery plugins do for similar options. But since it doesn't, you need to do this.

BTW, your use of the `role` attribute doesn't match the way it's intended to be used as part of [ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/). Standard roles are things like `button` and `menuitem`. You shouldn't abuse standard attributes like this, or make up custom attributes. If you want to put extra attributes in your elements, use `data-XXX` elements, e.g.

```
<div id="renable0" data-role="0">
```

You can access this in jQuery with `$(this).data('role')`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` won't refere to your element, you should keep a reference to it:

```
// loop through your elements
$("[id^='renable']").each(function () {
    // keep reference to it
    var $elem = $(this);

    // make it editInplace
    $elem.editInPlace({
        url: 'save.php',
        params: 'pos='+$elem.attr('role')
    });
});
```